# MySql JSON Index when value is greater than 255 characters

Tags: mysql, json, indexing

I'm trying to add an index to a JSON field in MySql 8.0.33 using

```sql
ALTER TABLE `json_test` ADD INDEX `test` ((
  CAST(data->>"$.test" as CHAR(255)) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
)) USING BTREE;
```

as recommended here https://planetscale.com/blog/indexing-json-in-mysql

This works without modifying the select query:

```sql
EXPLAIN select * from `json_test` where data->>"$.test" = "foo";
-- shows possible_keys = test
```

The problem is when the field is greater than 255 characters the insert fails

```sql
insert into `json_test` set data = '{"test":"a string greater than 255 characters ..."}';
-- Data truncated for functional index 'test' at row 1
```

I don't have much control over the select queries, so ideally I would not have to modify them. I'm using the Laravel query builder so I may be able to extend [MySqlGrammar.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php#L310).

I would also prefer not to disable the data truncated warnings in mysql's settings.

If the value is over 255 characters I don't really care if it's indexed since most people are searching for short strings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: how long is the data going to be?  depending on row format, you should be able to increase your index to 767 utf8mb4 characters.

Comment: @ysth Thanks but I experimented with different values for CHAR and it seems to max out at 512 for me. Unfortunately I need to support TEXT size values in that JSON field, even though in most rows, the value will be much smaller

Comment: then you will need to change your queries.  I suggest having a generated column that you index and use in your selects.

Comment: @ysth Thanks, that's what I was hoping to avoid but it looks like that might be the only way. Hopefully I can extend the ORM to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `json_test` ADD INDEX `test` ((
  LEFT(data->>"$.test", 255)) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
)) USING BTREE;
```

Try that.  I don't think the CAST is needed, but if it does, add it in.

You can lower the 255 if you desire.

Comment: Thanks, that works if I change my select query to `... where LEFT(data->>"$.test", 255) = ...` but I wanted to avoid that since I will have to extend the ORM. But since it looks like this is the only way I'll mark this as solved. Thanks!